# the closed unit ball in $l^p$ space is weakly compact

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to prove that $l^p$ is reflexive by showing that the closed unit ball in it is weakly compact.
Let $B_{l^p}$ = {$x=(\xi_i) \in l^p$ : ($\sum_{i=1}^\infty |\xi_i|^p)^{1/p} \leq 1$ }.
Since $l^p$ is a metric space, it is equivalent to show that the closed unit ball in $l^p$ is weakly sequentially compact. Let ($x_n$) be a sequence in $B_{l^p}$, where $x_m$ = ($\xi_1^{(m)}, \xi_2^{(m)}, ...)$. We want to show that this sequence has a weakly convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$ i.e. we want to find a $x \in l^p$ s.t. for every $f \in l^q$ where $1/p+1/q=1$ we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n_k})= f(x)$.
How can i continue? Any hints will be appreciated.
Any suggestion in another approach

Comment: If you really want to do it that way choose a subsequence making the first components converge, a sub-subsequence making the the second components converge and so on, and then consider a "diagonal subsequence" so that all components converge. Finally check that this convergence does not only hold component-wise but in fact weakly in $\ell^p$.

Comment: However, it seems that you already know that the dual of $\ell^p$ is $\ell^q$ and hence you know that the bidual of $\ell^p$ is $\ell^p$ (of course, you have to make precise the word "is" in that argument: reflexivity means that the canonocal inclusion of $X$ in its bidual is an isomorphism and not that $X$ is in some way isomorphic to $X^{\ast\ast}$).